# Get n-th element from end of list (table)

Tags: arrays, list, lua, lua-table, lua-5.2

If I have a list (table):

```
local list = {'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux'}
```

How do I get the *n*-th item from the end? (e.g., the last or second to last)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `list[#list+1-n]` to get the *n*-th entry from the end, counting from 1 as usual in Lua. So the last item has *n*=1.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
function getEntryFromEnd(table, entry)
    local count = (table and #table or false)
    if (count) then
        return table[count-entry];
    end
    return false;
end
```